# Error: root.rackStore.detach: The agent is not in a network

Tags: anylogic

There's a really weird issue happening in a model. I even noticed two unanswered questions about it on Stackoverflow. I tried to simplify the model as much as possible to understand the source of the problem with no luck.

The model is as simple as follows:
Source --> Rack Store -->  Sink

- Resource Pool assigned to Rack Store

In addition to a pallet rack and a home node for the resource.

The error I get after the agent is picked and stored in the rack is:

> root.rackStore.detach:  The agent is not in a network

That's how simple the model is:
[image]

I appreciate any support. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting, I found the answer. My scenario was a bit more complex than the attached image. It had a combine element before the rack pick and Agent Location (combined) was specified as a node within the network. However, that was not enough apparently for AnyLogic to understand that the combined agent is inside the network, so on exit, I added agent.moveTo(node) which is the same node specified as the agent location and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The whole rack system in Process modelling Library needs to be properly connected by paths, It can't be in free space. I was also facing a similar issue, connecting everything meticulously by paths is the only thing that worked for me.
Its better to use transporters in such cases.